# Make Div fixed bottom & scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a long page, with a fixed top 100px div, and a fixed 50px bottom div. However, I want the bottom div to scroll as you scroll down the page.

Its hard to explain, but the best example of this is on the front page of [PayPal.com](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/home#n1)

On the first page load, the bottom div looks like it is fixed, and as you adjust the height of the browser window, that div stays at the bottom. Yet as you scroll down the page it is not fixed.

Can anyone explain how they have done this? I am trying to re-create something similar, but cant see how they have managed it.

As far as I can see they have this html...

```
<div id="fixed-top">
  <header class="table-row">
    // header content
  </header>
  <div class="table-row table-row-two">
    // Video content
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    //bottom content
  </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS...

```
#fixed-top {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.table-row {
        display: table-row;
}
```

But that alone doesn't do it. I also can't see any js thats getting window height and applying it to the main fixed div.

Help! :)

EDIT:

Have just found a way to do it with javascript, controlling the height of the middle row using the window height, minus the 150px for the header and third row.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.table-row-two').css({'height':(($(window).height())-150)+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
    $('div.table-row-two').css({'height':(($(window).height())-150)+'px'});
    });
});
```

But saying that, Zwords CSS only method seems like a winner.

Comment: I don't see how the footer is fixed on your example??

Comment: Sorry, Its not fixed in CSS, but when changing the height of the window, the bottom white bar under the video acts as if it is fixed to the bottom of the window... until you scroll down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you'll need to set the height of the body and html tag, otherwise the table won't take the full screen. Then I altered your code, made it a bit easier.

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed-top">
    <header>
        // header content
    </header>
    <div>
        // Video content
    </div>
    <div>
        //bottom content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#fixed-top {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#fixed-top > * { /* makes all the direct children of #fixed-top a table row*/
    display: table-row;
    background: lightblue;
}
#fixed-top > *:nth-child(1) {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 40px;
}
#fixed-top > *:nth-child(3) {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 25%;
}
```

You can either set the height to a fix height (in px) or percentages. If you only give two of the three rows a height, the third one will automaticly fill up the rest space.

Also, check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4BCE6/).

Comment: Ah, this answer is just as good. And i love the * wildcard, I didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can come in handy. The benefit of this code that I spares you all the extra classes (and extra HTML code). Also when you maintain you sites, simple codes make it easier!

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you are looking for something like a sticky footer. So basically if the content is not enough, the footer should go sit at the bottom like its fixed, but if content comes in, it should scroll down like other content.

Try this - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/L4FsM/2/) / [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/L4FsM/2/show/)

Using `display:table;`,`display:table-row;`,`min-height` to adjust to screen

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">menu</div>
    <div class="row">content</div>
    <div class="row">footer</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">content1</div>
    <div class="row">content2</div>
    <div class="row">content3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.wrapper .row{
    display:table-row;
    background-color:rgb(220,220,220);
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(1){
    min-height:15px;
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(2){
    height:100%;
    background-color:white;
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(3){
    min-height:15px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with jQuery using `$(window).height()` and subtracting your footer/header's heights. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qaLu/;) for an example.